# Changing vertical scroll to horizontal

Tags: html, css, scroll

This seems to have been asked before without a sufficient answer. I have absolutely no knowledge of how to do this (including no plugins).  I want my website to scroll horizontally when I actively scroll down vertically.

Some examples of what I mean:
http://hotdot.pro/en/
and
http://mashup.ikm.gda.pl/

To be clear, I don't care about the parallax effect that both of these websites utilize. I just want to scroll horizontally.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the jquery.mousewheel.js file on the second link that you copied? It looks like it's overriding the mousewheel, and "replacing" the vertical movement for horizontal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:
You need to add a script reference to jquery and to the [mouse wheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel).
And then use this JS:

```
$(function() {
   $("body").mousewheel(function(evt, chg) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (chg * 50); //need a value to speed up the change
      evt.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Script References:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

*you can directly use the first one, jquery script, as is because it is a public repository, but the second, the mousewheel.js will require you to save the .js file somewhere on your server and provide a link to it (similar to how you provide links for images in the `src` attribute).*

Plugin: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Can you tell me how to reference the jquery plugin? I've never used jquery or any plugin so I'm not familiar with it.


Edit: nevermind, I think I figured it out.

Comment: I added the script reference info, do note that you will need to host mousewheel.js yourself

Comment: Do I have to do anything different for firefox? This appears to work for my website on chrome, but not firefox.

Comment: Try this demo link on firefox: [link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/). If this works, try using this JQuery Version: 1.3.2

Comment: Ya I figured it out. You have to change $("body") into $("html, body").

Comment: Glad it is working for you - firefox can be a bit picky when it comes to selectors.

Answer (score 24):

This can be solved in native JavaScript, without any library.

## Example code

```js
function transformScroll(event) {
  if (!event.deltaY) {
    return;
  }

  event.currentTarget.scrollLeft += event.deltaY + event.deltaX;
  event.preventDefault();
}

var element = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
element.addEventListener('wheel', transformScroll);
```

## Explanation

While this solution does not lean on any library, it also takes other usage scenario's into account. When scrolling on a touchpad for example, the other solutions that lean on a single delta value all fall apart.

There are always multiple ways of scrolling with an input device. Laptops have touchpads, phones have touchscreens, mouses have scroll wheels. On top of that, you can modify your scroll direction for a scroll wheel by holding shift.

When preventing the default behaviour, we should also include the other possible directions a user can scroll in. Luckily screens only have two dimensions, so adding deltaY to deltaX covers all cases in this scenario.

Comment: If you use track-pad in Windows with Chrome, this piece of code will override/disable the pinch function which is greatly inconvenience for reading.

Comment: You can remove the `+ event.deltaX` & `event.preventDefault()` parts from my code. But that will give the vertical elastic overscroll, which you kind-of do not want either. It does work, though.

Comment: See a demo of the stripped down version that does not prevent default behaviour: https://codepen.io/guidobouman/pen/LYpPawd

Comment: Even though this is a great solution. It does not work on touch devices like the iPad. I think there is no way around listening to the `touchmove` event and map its Y delta to the horizontal scroll position.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution to this if anyone is working on Chrome. The star selector is what made it functional for Chrome, and the html selector should enable the functionality on Firefox as well.

```
$(function() {
    $("html, body, *").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that bind an event listener to... literally every element on the page?

Comment: Yes it would, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

#### Pure `CSS` solution

**You dont need `Javascript` for this** 
For more information: https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

body {
  background: #111;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(250px + 1px);
  max-height: 750px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1px;
  background: #abc;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-250px);
          transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-250px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
          transform-origin: right top;
}
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #cab;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
          transform-origin: right top;
}

.squares {
  padding: 250px 0 0 0;
}
.squares > div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper squares">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
  <div>item 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be warned that this way of doing it is really nice if it worked well across more devices. All Apple mobile devices are excludes as are quite a lot of other touch based devices.

Comment: it is possible to detect user device touch capabilities with CSS and switch to a normal horizontal scroll to solve the problem mentioned by @Maarten. but it is just too much work. not to mention that since we are using transform for this, it is possible to have blurry rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Javascript For this, you can achieve this through CSS only

Just Follow the example

```
.main-div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.child.element{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 300px; //according to your need
    max-width: 300px; //according to your need
}
```